# Data not appending with R when writing

Tags: r

I am writing output to a file but the data is not appending. It is creating the last row each time. The code is as follows

```
op <- function(crime) {
filename <- paste(crime,".txt")
fileconn <- file(filename)
cat(nthecrime, file=fileconn, sep="  ",append=TRUE)
#write(nthecrime,file=fileconn, ncolumns=9, append=TRUE,sep="\t")
close(fileconn)
}
```

Both cat & write create a new file each time I call the above lines instead of appending. What am I missing?

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `?cat` help:

> append     logical. Only used if the argument file is the name of file
>   (and not a connection or "|cmd"). If TRUE output will be appended to
>   file; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents of file.

You should use `filename`, not `fileconn`. Try

```
cat(nthecrime, file=filename, sep="  ",append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thx. That worked. append applies only filename and not fileconn. Regards Ganesh